# Mysql: String comparison using = operator

Tags: mysql, join, operators, left-join

I'm new to mysql and I'm learning join queries now. when I compare strings I got weird output that mentioned below. I have two tables

```
   MariaDB [test]> select * from classroom;
    +---------+-----------+
    | subject | classroom |
    +---------+-----------+
    | maths   |         1 |
    | englishs|         2 |
    +---------+-----------+
```

Table student:

```
  MariaDB [test]> select * from student;
  +------+------+---------+
  | id   | name | subject |
  +------+------+---------+
  |    1 | abc  | maths   |
  |    2 | abcd | english |
  +------+------+---------+
```

I have tried this query

```
 select b.classroom,a.name,b.subject from student a left join classroom b
 on a.subject = b.subject ;
```

and the output is like,

```
  +-----------+------+---------+
  | classroom | name | subject |
  +-----------+------+---------+
  |         1 | abc  | maths   |
  |      NULL | abcd | NULL    |
  +-----------+------+---------+
```

I don't understand why am getting second row if the strings are doesn't match in both tables.

Comment: That's the nature of LEFT JOIN.  Gets all records from student, even if there is no match.  Try this out:  `SELECT b.classroom,a.name,b.subject FROM student a LEFT JOIN classroom b
 on a.subject = b.subject  WHERE b.subject IS NOT NULL` OR ``SELECT b.classroom,a.name,b.subject FROM student a INNER JOIN classroom b
 on a.subject = b.subject `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with string comparison.

You are using an **outer join**, but the result you are expecting is the one that **inner joins** gives.

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins) for a good explanation about inner and outer joins.

From that post:

> - An **inner join** of A and B gives the result of A intersect B, i.e. the inner part of a Venn diagram intersection.
> - An **outer join** of A and B gives the results of A union B, i.e. the outer parts of a Venn diagram union.

Answer (score 1):

try this may be this will work.

```
 select b.classroom,a.name,b.subject from student a,classroom b where a.subject = b.subject
```